# how to call a closure with argument in a function

Tags: ios, swift

```
func Test(clo: @escaping (String)->Void) 
{
  clo($0)
}
```

it return an error that says :

> anonymous closure argument not contained in a closure

I want to be able to do:

```
Test{ n in 
var name = n
name = "Taha"
print(name)}
```

instead of hard coded String

```
func Test(clo: @escaping (String)->Void) 
{
  clo("Taha")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not how closures work in Swift. And the code you wrote doesn't even make sense. Why do you assign `n` to `name` then change the value of `name` just to print it ?

The function with the closure will call the closure with a given value. You can think of closures as lambda functions. Here is an example:

```swift
func test(_ closure: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
    closure("My string")
}

test { str in
    print(str)  //prints " My string"
}
```

For what you are trying to achieve, just use a String parameter in your function:

```swift
func test(_ str: String) {
    print(str)
}

test("My string") // prints "My string"
```

Or use a closure that takes Void:

```swift
func test(_ closure: @escaping (Void) -> Void) {
    closure()
}

test { 
    print("My string") // prints "My string"
}
```